# WordPress's wp-admin panel weird behavior

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, docker

I installed an official [WP docker container](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/d8e5577dcc7096d2b694dda433e2b5c7c4561a82/php5.6/apache/Dockerfile). Container running in front of nginx instance.

Here is the .htaccess file that I inject to container:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Nginx just proxies `/wp` to appropriate path. 
The problem is the following:
`https://example.com/wp/` and `https://example.com/wp/hello-post/`
work fine. But once I try to get an access to `https://example.com/wp/wp-admin/` it redirects me all the time to `https://example.com/wp-admin/` i.e. ignores `wp` subfolder.. I tried to use [.htaccess which comes by default](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/d8e5577dcc7096d2b694dda433e2b5c7c4561a82/php5.6/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L55) - exactly same story.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing! Is there any use behind installing wp docker? Seems like a caching system; however I can link you to better caching combo. Coming to your problem, Where did you install your WordPress in a sub folder '/wp/'? And the reason for your wp-admin is redirected back to example.com/wp-admin is because in wp_options table your WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME need to point to 'http://example.com/wp/" instead of 'http://example.com'. You can change them without accessing your database by just editting your wp-config.php

`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/wp/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/wp/');`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I made the changes in DB already.. I.e. change home/siteurl to point to /wp. Do I still have to change wp-config?

Comment: Now tell me is your wordpress installed in /wp/ folder ?? If so then you need to change the .htaccess

Comment: You mean to set a Rewritebase to /wp?

Comment: this is the standard .htaccess if you want to try:
`http://pastebin.com/8LLmqgh2`

Comment: I tried both ways.. Both don't work. In addition, if I specify `RewriteBase /wp/` - and enable permalink post name options I can't open none of the posts  - 500 Internal error

Comment: Something must be wrong. Try now to rename .htaccess to .htaccess.bak or remove it and see if it fixes.

Comment: If I do that, docker image will create a default htaccess described here: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/d8e5577dcc7096d2b694dda433e2b5c7c4561a82/php5.6/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L56 Tried it, did not work

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote to you in github seems to be an issue with the container.

if you check the container `docker exec --interactive --tty your_container /bin/bash` and cat `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` you'll notice

This issue could be due to the configuration of the apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With `AllowOverride None` the `.htaccess` file is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try This

   place your wordpress installation in /wp folder inside /var/www/html
2. Or

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In my case, this resolves the issue.

also, check extra work on my **wp-config.php**

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

/blog/wp-admin/ here blog is sub directory path.